# What is consensus mechanism used by committer in hyperledger-fabric v1.0?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

After reading official docs of hyperledger-fabric v1.0 I understood that there are two types of peers

1. endorsing peers
2. Committer

I just want to know how does committer validate the transaction? What is underlying mechanism or algorithm used by committer to validate? As in bitcoin miners calculate difficulty and hash ,similarly how does committer do validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to be perfectly clear, these are processes in a peer. In most cases the peer will perform both functions, however, you could choose to have a peer only commit.

There are a series of checks and signoffs that occur starting from the endorsement to final commitment. Check out slide 14 in FabricNext-Community.pdf at https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-37 for the specific low level flow.

Answer (score 0):

so far, by read/write set of the chaincode, each peer will calculate the R&W sets, and get the promised result, then the consensus process, if the endorsement policy passed, the committer will commit the Tx finally.